# DAX filter measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to using DAX in Power BI so i hope i am asking my question properly. I am currently based data in one table based on their type which is pulled from another table and currently i was to create this measure:

```
 Results = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTA('table_level'[level]),
        'table_type'[type] IN { "school" }
    )
```

So currently, this is returning a list of rows which is a 'School' but i am getting a list that contains: preschool, pre-k, elementary, middle school, high school. I want to filter so i can just get rows elementary and middle school and create another column in which it will be called 'Other' and check to see if i have a row where the level contains a 'pre' that will get pushed into it. So preschool and pre-k will get pushed into the Other column. Is it possible to do this all in one measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these two measures

```
onlyElementary_middleSchool = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTA('table_level'[level]),
        FILTER(VALUES('table_type'[type]), 'table_type'[type]="elementary" || 'table_type'[type]="middle school"
    )

others = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTA('table_level'[level]),
        FILTER(VALUES('table_type'[type]), 'table_type'[type]="elementary" && 'table_type'[type]="middle school"
    )
```

Comment: I will give this a try but i was wondering for the 'others' shouldn't the filter check if the value/text checks if it contains 'pre' rather than specifying the types?

Comment: You want to bucket everything together in a single bucket that are `elementary` or `middle school` if I understand correctly and everything else goes into the `others` bucket..am I right? If yes, DAX does not need be burdened additionally with `CONTAINSTRING`

Comment: So i was able to filter using the first calculation but the second one for the other I believe i will need to check the string value because my data contains other values in `table_type` that i want to ignore like college and university.

Comment: What is the logic for the 2nd calculation. What do you want to identify as others -"preschool" only ?

Comment: Anything that will contain "pre". My data contains "preschool, pre-school, pre-k"

Comment: Will it be something like: `COUNTA('table_level'[level]),
        FILTER(VALUES('table_type'[type]), CONTAINSSTRING('table_type'[type], "pre")))` ?

Comment: It would be this `Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTA('Table'[Column1]),FILTER(VALUES('Table'[Column1]),CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[Column1],"pre")=TRUE()))`

Comment: For some reason when i type this in - for 'CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[Column1], "pre")... i am getting 'Table'[Column1] as unexpected parameter.